# UINavigationbar masks item on return

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation bar button item with a shadow. When my controller appears the first time, the shadow shows fine:

[image]

When I navigate somewhere and return back, the navigation bar cuts the shadow:

[image]

Comment: Remove the shadow on navigation and reapply it when navigation is finished.

Comment: Thank you, but even if I reapply the shadow on viewDidAppear the bar cuts it (